Android check google account in login on device
I want to intergrate passkey on Android device.
So l want to check wether my device had login google.
How can l do that? GetGoogleIdOption always need a serverid, but i do not need my google account login my app, only need this account access to google password manage.
l want to check that google account is login on my Samgung phone.

You want to add something to your question please use the edit mode instead of creating a new question.
